# Can you shorten this code to single liner?

Tags: c#

Is this code convertible to 1 liner or at the max 2 liner?

```
int indexOfSpace = response.IndexOf(" ");
int indexOfNewLine = response.IndexOf("\n");
string responseSubString = "";

if (indexOfNewLine > 0 && indexOfNewLine < indexOfSpace)
{
    responseSubString = response.Substring(0, response.IndexOf("\n"));
}
else
{
    responseSubString = response.Substring(0, response.IndexOf(" "));
}
```

Basically, I am trying to get the first word from a string that may contain a space or a new line after the first word.

Comment: Just one line :) `int indexOfSpace = response.IndexOf(" ");  int indexOfNewLine = response.IndexOf("\n");  string responseSubString = "";    if (indexOfNewLine > 0 && indexOfNewLine < indexOfSpace)  {      responseSubString = response.Substring(0, response.IndexOf("\n"));  }  else  {      responseSubString = response.Substring(0, response.IndexOf(" "));  }`

Comment: @EZI :) also `string.Join("", response.TakeWhile(c => c!=' ' && c != '\n'))` is more honest one-line...

Comment: `responseSubString = str.Split(new[]{' ','\n'},2).First();`

Comment: @Habib Why `FirstOrDefault` ? Split always returns an array with 1 element for sure. You can use `First` or just access array[0];

Comment: @SriramSakthivel, Yup right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
responseSubString = response.Split(' ', '\n')[0];
```

This code splits your string by space and new line symbol and returns the first member. It assumes string is not null, in which case you would get a `NullReferenceException`.

For better control you can use the overload with extra parameters, which define how many string items to use in split operation (you don't need more than 1) and options to remove empty strings (if you have multiple strings in a row):

```
responseSubString = response.Split(new char[] {' ', '\n'}, 2, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[0]
```

Comment: It does unnecessarily spend the effort to split the entire string, looking for every single space and new line, rather than just the first.

Comment: `responseSubString = response != null ? response.Split(' ', '\n')[0] : null;` returns the first word of the string, or null if the string is null.

Comment: I have tried your code. It gives me the result when response string contains a new line just after the first word. But it does not work, if first word is followed by a space.

Comment: @Servy That's right, thanks for noticing that. I updated the answer

Comment: @Servy If splitting all over the string is a concern, you could limit it using the overload of split method which takes count as parameter and provide `2` as a input for it. It will  not split the string fully, but just once.

Comment: @dotnetom Yeah, still has the issue of unnecessarily parsing the whole string though.

Comment: Oops! I was wrong. It works fine. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Thank you for the tip, I updated the answer accordingly

Comment: You do not want to have `RemoveEmptyEntries`.  That will in fact *break* the code if there is an empty string, or if there is a delimiter at the start of the string.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively to using String.Split, this Regex should also work:

```
//Find the first word in a string
string myString = "thisisthefirstword of this\nstring\n";
string firstWord = Regex.Match(myString, @"^([\w\-]+)").Value;

// firstWord: "thisisthefirstword"
```

However, the accepted answer is about 10x faster (2 minutes versus 20 minutes for 1 million executions).

Comment: Thanks for trying to answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

Here's five:

- Regular Expression: anchored match from start of string to 1st whitespace

  ```
  firstWord = Regex.Match(   text , @"^\S+"       ).Value ;
  ```
- Regular Expression: trim from 1st whitespace to end-of-string using anchored match

  ```
  firstWord = Regex.Replace( text , @"\s.*$" , "" ) ;
  ```
- Linq

  ```
  firstWord = text.TakeWhile( c => !char.IsWhiteSpace(c) ).Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (sb,c) => sb.Append(c) ).ToString();
  ```
- Two variants using `string.Substring()` and `string.IndexofAny()`

  ```
  // this will fail if the string has no whitespace
  firstWord = text.Substring(0, text.IndexOfAny( " \r\n\t\f\v".ToCharArray() ) ) ;

  // this will NOT fail in the same condition ... at the expense of creating a temporary
  firstWord = (text+" ").Substring(0, text.IndexOfAny( " \r\n\t\f\v".ToCharArray() ) );
  ```

One should note that none of these are likely to be as speedy as the simple and obvious:

```
public static string FirstWord( this string s )
{
  if ( s == null ) throw new ArgumentNullException("s");

  int i = 0 ;
  while ( i < s.Length && !char.isWhiteSpace(s[i]) )
  {
    ++i ;
  }

  if ( i == 0 ) throw new InvalidOperationException("no word found");
  return s.Substring(0,i);

}
```